# How long submitted DS-160 is valid?

Tags: h1-visa

I am working in USA under H1B. I am from India. My H1B has recently extended. I am planning to visit India in February 2017. I have to go to for visa stamping since my H1B is expired.

I am wondering if I can fill DS-160 and submit it now and schedule appointment for February or fill DS-160 and submit and schedule appointment for February in December.

How many days the submitted is the DS-160 valid for?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a response published in [The Hindu Ask the Consul](http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Hyderabad/bar-code-valid-as-long-as-information-given-is-accurate/article798766.ece), a weekly feature in which US Consulate officials reply to those with any queries about visas or services. While not recent, the article includes a contact e-mail for the Consulate.

> The bar code on your DS-160 confirmation page is valid as long as the information you listed in the DS-160 form is accurate. You may only use a bar code once. If you need to update your DS-160 to reflect a new job, to correct information, or to upload a more recent photo, a new confirmation page with a new bar code will be generated. If you schedule an appointment with the old barcode and later update your DS-160 and receive a new barcode, you will need to bring both confirmation pages with you to the Consulate General at the time of your appointment.